# Слитно или раздельно? Объяснить легче, чем написать.

Tags: орфография

«В зависимости от смысла не с краткими прилагательными, как и с полными, пишется то слитно, то раздельно; ср.: наша семья небогата (примерно то же, что бедна) - наша семья не богата (т.е. среднего достатка)».Так  можно  объяснить уже написанное. А как быть школьникам во время диктанта?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, давать как основное слитное написание, а раздельное только для случаев вроде противопоставления:

> Наша семья не богата, а бедна.

НО!

> Река неглубока, но холодна.

Answer (score 1):

Я не совсем согласна с Екатериной, что на слух понятен смысл. Конечно, не всегда. И времени размышлять у ученика нет. В данном случае написание слова помогает понять смысл, поэтому не грех и  подсказать (не прямо, а так, чтобы значение стало понятно). Ведь любой диктант, даже контрольный, проводится именно для того, чтобы учить, а не ловить на ошибках. Кроме того, тексты диктантов подбираются и выверяются заранее именно затем, чтобы избежать двусмысленности.

Answer (score 0):

Между прочим, эта ошибка (на НЕ с прилагательными) считается негрубой. Пол-ошибки, так сказать. Если, кроме неё, других ошибок нет, Вы и пятёрку за диктант можете получить. А если серьёзно, то в 99 случаях из 100 бывает ясно из контекста, что имел в виду автор: бедна семья была или среднего достатка... Так что вчитывайтесь и вслушивайтесь в текст.